# Hot network questions not stable anymore?

Tags: support, hot-questions

Sometimes, when I click a link and wait for a page to load, I look at the Hot Network Questions. Sometimes I see something interesting right before the page loads, so I click the Back button.

If I'm not mistaken, previously I got back to the exact same list and could open the interesting question in a new tab.

Now it seems since a few days I get a new list of Hot Network Questions with every refresh.

Did something change on SE or is it an issue with my browser?

Comment: related: [“Hot Network Questions” randomizes too much when navigation in browser history](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229052/165773)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I should have put it on Meta Stack*exchange* in the first place and over there a duplicate already exists.